# Confusion about a definition of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In my complex analysis textbook in addition to the "formal definition" of compact sets using convergent series there is a definition  of compact sets that states:
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $K$ of $X$ is said to be compact if for every collection $\mathcal C$ of  subsets οf X that satisfy $K\subseteq\bigcup_{A\in C}A$ there exist $A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n$ such that $K\subseteq A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3\cup \dots \cup A_n$. What I cannot understand is how we can use this definition to derive the two main properties of $K$ that it will be closed and bounded. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Comment: Your question is very *classical*. The fact that you work in a metric space is important for separation and therefore being closed.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry but I still cannot understand why this definition implies that $K$ is closed. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @KaniPen The link provided by [Randall](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464495/randall) contains the proof you're looking for.

Comment: @KaniPen you should pay more attention to the first comment. You're asking about the Heine-Borel Theorem, but for metric spaces rather than in $R^k$ only. See if the proofs on wikipedia work for metric spaces also instead of just $R^k.$

Comment: The second definition (from a covering one can extract a finite covering) should be for coverings by _open_ subsets. If any subsets are allowed, take singleton subsets (each element alone in its subset) and it will be impossible to extract a finite covering. By the way, this definition of compacity is the most usual one; the one on metric spaces is usually derived from it (and does not apply to topological spaces).

Comment: $K$ is obviously bounded since it is covered by a finite number of balls of radius $1$. As to your main question (prove that $K$ is closed), it was answered by Henno Brandsma in [Prove compact subsets of metric spaces are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111662/prove-compact-subsets-of-metric-spaces-are-closed).

Comment: see the proof that compact subsets of a hausdorff space are closed and notice that a metric space is hausdorff

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, I don't see where it is said that $K$ is covered by a finite number of balls of radius 1. We know nothing about the $A_i$.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni Apply the OP's definition to $K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in K}B(x,1)$.